SIGSTOP action delay is unbounded the first time when sent once, but delay is immediate the second time it is sent?
I have been using SIGSTOP to test a system that manages the state of processes.  I've noticed recently that when I send SIGSTOP once to a process in the system, the "STOPPED" process is still using CPU cycles for an indefinite amount of time.  I found this post
Time to stop a Linux process using SIGSTOP
which would seem to explain why that is.
However, if I send SIGSTOP to the same process again, the CPU usage of that process immediately goes to 0.
Can anyone explain why that is?
Thank you,
Jason

What process do you stop? How do you send the signal? How do you see that "the process is still using CPU cycles"?

"What process do you stop?"  I'm not sure how to answer this without getting too complicated, but I'm stopping a process that can be started at any point once the Linux system has completed its boot process.

"How do you send the signal? "  pkill -SIGSTOP <process_name>

" How do you see that "the process is still using CPU cycles"?"     top

what was the state of the process prior to sending the signal, what state is the process after the signal has been sent, have you tried tracing the process to see what it's doing after the signal has been sent ?, is this a threaded process ? ...

Can you confirm that pkill is sending signal to the same process, not to another process with the same name? E.g. with pkill -e or using kill <PID>? I would speculate that first time parent tracks child process's state changed, terminates it and starts new process with the same name. Can you reproduce the behavior with a simple process which prints a message in infinite loop, for example, started from shell?

@ticktalk - Yes this is a threaded process.  By "tracing" the process, do you mean strace?

@dimich, when i use prep with the same process name only one PID is returned.  So, I think the signal is only being sent to one process.  I don't see a -e argument for pkill.  I process I am trying to SIGSTOP should be killed by another process.  That other process kills the SIGSTOPed process only when SIGSTOP is sent the second time.

Your question requires more clarity. What is parent process of a process you are trying to stop? What does it do when child status changed?

for a threaded process it's possible 1 or more of the threads haven't been terminated - ie waiting for I/O to complete for example. what is the process (and any threads) actually doing when the SIGSTOP is sent ?, share your code please

@dimich -  I'm afraid I can't share the code as it is code that my employer is developing.  However, I'm not sure why the behavior of the application I am testing makes any difference.  The signal man page                     https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html                                                 says                                                                                                                                the signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

, @ticktalk - please see above.

The only mention of I/O blocking I see comes from this section of the signal man page:               read(2), readv(2), write(2), writev(2), and ioctl(2) calls on
"slow" devices.  A "slow" device is one where the I/O call may
block for an indefinite time, for example, a terminal, pipe,
or socket.  If an I/O call on a slow device has already
transferred some data by the time it is interrupted by a
signal handler, then the call will return a success status
...  However, again SIGSTOP can't be handled.

can you recreate this scenario at will or is it just occasionally happening ... (can you also respond as to the parent process state at the time of sending the signal) - copy/paste actuals not dialog please.

@ticktalk, yes, as far as I am concerned, I can recreate this scenario at will.  Every time I've tried sending SIGISTOP to this process once, it keeps going (i.e. this process is consuming CPU cycles).  What about the state of the parent process do you want to know, whether or not it is running?  At this point, I can't say that for certain, since I wasn't trying to observe the parent process.  However, I'm reasonably certain that the parent process is always running, because when this child finally pauses, the parent logs a message noting that the child has paused and then kills the child.

Alo, the process I'm talking about writes its own log messages (i.e. messages written a file on disk).  After the first SIGSTOP is sent, this process continues to write log messages.

@user2985081 >SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored It cannot by a process to which signal is sent. But it's parent process can detect that child process is stopped. For example, if parent process sends SIGCONT to child process when it is stopped first time, child process will resume and continue to run. From user's point of view it will look exactly like you described. Not knowing a logic behind parent process of process you are stopping, every answer is a speculation and "coffee reading".

@dimich, the parent listens to the child through a form of Inter Process Communication.  In particular, the child sends a heartbeat to the parent to let the parent know that it is alive.  My desire is to stop this heartbeat using SIGSTOP.  I've spoken to the developer and even he can't explain why SIGSTOP doesn't work the first time it is sent.

@user2985081 Does parent monitor child's process state? If yes, how does it do monitoring? Does it install SIGCHLD handler? If yes, what does handler do? Does it call waitpid() or waitid()? With what flags? SIGCHLD is sent to parent not only when child process is terminated but also when child is stopped.
